# Init with Cucumber and Protractor

Tags: angularjs, node.js, frameworks, protractor, cucumber

I'm new on angular testing and I've seen that Protractor with Cucumber it's a good idea. My problem is to get configured all the staff, when I try to install protractor-cucumber-framework it's always saying that Cucumber 2.0 is needed, but I've installed globally yet.

Also I have a doubt where I have to do

```
npm install --save-dev protractor-cucumber-framework
```

It has to be on the root of my project?

I'm working on Windows and sorry if this look simple but I'm really new with this.

Answer (score 0):

I understand your issue that you are not able to install protractor with Cucumber, Please follow the below instructions it will workout.

**Install npm package to dev dependencies**

npm install protractor-cucumber --save-dev

Usage
**Install Cucumber**

npm install -g cucumber

**Install protractor**

npm install -g protractor

**Update webdriver**

webdriver-manager update

**Start Selenium**

webdriver-manager start